# Proxying Anonymous Objects across AppDomain boundaries

Tags: c#, proxy, razor, appdomain, anonymous-types

One of the most requested features I'm trying to iron out for [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) vNext is support for loading template assemblies in a separate `AppDomain` so we can unload the assemblies when we need to. Great feature request, but it has the knock-on effect of introducing constraints on the possible model types that can be injected into templates.

One of the nice features of the current v2.1 release is the ability to use anonymous types as models. We do the work of determining that the model type in the template is an anonymous type, and we set the base template as `TemplateBase<dynamic>`. The runtime binder takes care late-bound calls for the model members for us. All very nice.

When we introduce support for running templates in a separate `AppDomain` we now have a constraint that models can only be of types that are `[Serializable]` (which is implied through inheritance of `MarshalByRefObject`). Anonymous types are not serialisable, and are also `private`.

My thinking would be to somehow make a proxy model (declared as `dynamic`) in the template base which despatches calls to the model (which would be in the calling domain, not the domain the template is running in). In essence:

**Template**:

```
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

The call to `@Model.Name` would do something like:

```
Template.Model (ModelProxy) -> GetMember(Name) -> |BOUNDARY| -> Model.Name
```

Does anyone know or have experience with the best method of attempting to proxy a call to an anonymous (or `dynamic` object) in another `AppDomain`?

Importantly, I'm not trying to push the anonymous object through `AppDomain` boundary, that can't be done.

Comment: I have an answer for you but it's more complex than can be posted here...I'll try and condense it but the source will go to my blog...when I figure out how to explain it. There are some minor things that are a bit...wonky...gonna try and fix those first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Assuming you know about reflection and creating a new `AppDomain`. Which I know you know how to do... :)

I've created two helper classes that will allow you to pass anonymous objects. `ProxyAnonymousObject` and `ProxyDynamicObject`. You create the `ProxyAnonymousObject` in the first `AppDomain` and use the `ProxyDynamicObject` in the other `AppDomain`. (both of these objects exist in the primary `AppDomain` library)

```
[Serializable]
public class ProxyAnonymousObject : ISerializable {

    static Dictionary<string, Type> cached = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    object model;

    public Dictionary<string, object> ModelProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public ProxyAnonymousObject(object model) { this.model = model; }
    public ProxyAnonymousObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctx) {
        try {

            string fieldName = string.Empty;
            object fieldValue = null;

            foreach (var field in info) {
                fieldName = field.Name;
                fieldValue = field.Value;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldName))
                    continue;

                if (fieldValue == null)
                    continue;

                ModelProperties.Add(fieldName, fieldValue);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            var x = e;
        }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {

        foreach (var pi in model.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            info.AddValue(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(model, null), pi.PropertyType);
        }

    }
}

public class ProxyDynamicObject : DynamicObject{
    internal ProxyAnonymousObject Proxy { get; set; }

    public ProxyDynamicObject(ProxyAnonymousObject model) {
        this.Proxy = model;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        result = Proxy.ModelProperties[binder.Name];
        return true;
    }
}
```

To get this to work in your `MarshalByRefObject` inherited class you just set the target `dynamic object` equal to a `new ProxyDynamicObject(model)`. In the example I've written up I make a call like this.

```
instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var setModel = type.GetMethod("SetModel", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var render = type.GetMethod("Render", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

setModel.Invoke(instance, new object[] { new ProxyDynamicObject(model) });
render.Invoke(instance, null);
```

I've written a blog post about it http://buildstarted.com/2011/06/28/getting-anonymous-types-to-cross-the-appdomain-boundary/ to explain it in a bit more detail. (though it's something I'm not very good at)

There are definitely problems with this implementation. It doesn't support nested Anonymous Types and I'm fairly certain it will break in general. But it's definitely something to get you on the right track.